# Prove that for all real numbers $a, b$ we will have inequality: $ab(a+2)(b+4)$+$5a^{2}$+$7b^2$+$10a$+$28b$+$29$ ≥$ 0$

Tags: inequality, quadratics, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

My teacher told me that use Cauchy-Schwarz,  but I still can’t prove the inequality.

I just tried taking it all apart and make $(2a+2b)^2$ because it has $8ab$ and I don't what to do after.

Can anyone give me some tips?

Comment: I just tried taking it all apart and make (2a+2b)^2 because it has 8ab and I don't what to do after

Comment: @ths You should add your attempts to solve it into the question, not as comments. For a hint, you can look at this as a quadratic in either $a$ or $b$, then remember what the conditions are for a quadratic to be always non-negative.

Comment: @ths The minimum occurs for $(a,b)=(-1,-2).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to show:
$$5(a+1)^2+7(b+2)^2+a(a+2)\cdot b(b+4)-4\geqslant 0$$
This suggests using $x = a+1, y=b+2$, so we may write this equivalently as
$$5x^2+7y^2+(x^2-1)(y^2-4)-4= x^2+6y^2+x^2y^2\geqslant 0$$
which is obvious.

*P.S.: I am not sure if finding a suitable CS inequality is worth the effort here...*

Comment: This looks right, thanks a lot